# ListView Not getting refreshed when using filter

Tags: android, listview, android-filter

There are many similar questions asked but none of them were helpful to me... i m filtering the list based on whole word but the list is not getting refreshed and not displayed.Below is my listview and filter code...so plz check out... thanks in advance

```
public class MyInventoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductInventoryItem>
    implements OnClickListener {

private final Context context;
ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem> itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem>();
private ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem> originalList;
private MFilter filter;

public MyInventoryAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem> itemsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.custom_product_inventory, itemsArrayList);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    this.originalList = new ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem>();
    this.originalList.addAll(itemsArrayList);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new MFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // 1. Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater
    View convertView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_inventory,
            parent, false);

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    LinearLayout llview = (LinearLayout) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.inventory_row);
    TextView txtpname = (TextView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
    TextView txtpdesc = (TextView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.tvProductDesc);
    TextView txtpcost = (TextView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice1);
    TextView txtcat = (TextView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.tvProductcat);
    TextView txtsubcat = (TextView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.tvProductsubcat);
    // holder.btn_edit = (ImageButton)
    // convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    ImageView chk_check = (ImageView) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.check);

    // 4. Set the text for textView
    final ProductInventoryItem rowItem = (ProductInventoryItem) getItem(position);

    txtpname.setText(rowItem.getPname());
    txtpdesc.setText(rowItem.getPdesc());
    txtpcost.setText(rowItem.getPcost());
    txtcat.setText(rowItem.getCat());
    txtsubcat.setText(rowItem.getSubcat());

    boolean status = rowItem.isStatus();

    String url = "null";// rowItem.getImgurl();

    chk_check.setTag(rowItem);

    if (status) {
        chk_check.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_mark);
        llview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
    } else {
        chk_check.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_old);
        llview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
    }

    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        // System.out.println("myadap:" + url);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera);
    } else {
        Bitmap bitmap, bit;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
        bit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 75, 75, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
    }

    chk_check.setOnClickListener(this);

    // 5. retrn rowView
    return convertView1;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProductInventoryItem item = (ProductInventoryItem) v.getTag();
    String pid = item.getPid();
    System.out.println("pid" + pid);
    if (!item.isStatus()) {
        item.setStatus(true);
    } else {
        item.setStatus(false);
    }

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class MFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            result.values = originalList;
            result.count = originalList.size();
        } else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem> nItemList = new ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem>();

            for (ProductInventoryItem listp : originalList) {
                if (listp.getCat().toUpperCase()
                        .startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())
                        || listp.getSubcat()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .startsWith(
                                        constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    nItemList.add(listp);
            }

            result.values = nItemList;
            result.count = nItemList.size();
            System.out.println(nItemList.size());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {

        itemsArrayList = (ArrayList<ProductInventoryItem>)results.values;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
         clear();
         for(int i = 0, l = itemsArrayList.size(); i < l; i++)
          add(itemsArrayList.get(i));
         notifyDataSetInvalidated();        
      }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default [ArrayAdapter.getFilter()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getFilter%28%29) returns a filter called ArrayFilter that is doing something similar.

Description of this filter says:

> An array filter constrains the content of the array adapter with a
>   prefix. Each item that does not start with the supplied prefix is
>   removed from the list.

So just have a look in there(grepcode) how it should be implemented. Maybe you don't actually need to implement it by your own. If you do, just copy - paste the code and modify to solve all compilation issues.